# FragmentTransaction seems to be slow and laggy

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have a problem with Android code:

This piece of code works perfectly:

```
CalendarDialogFagment dialog = new CalendarDialogFagment();
dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog_calendar");
```

But when I try to show it like a fragment (in tablet-version) it becomes very laggy and slow, taking large delays while updating fragment's layout.

Here is the code:

```
    if (calendarContainer == null)
        calendarContainer = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.games_calendar_container);
        boolean isShown = calendarContainer.isShown();

        if (!isShown) {
            calendarContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (calendarFragment == null) {
                calendarFragment = new CalendarDialogFagment();
                calendarFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);

                FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.games_calendar, calendarFragment, "tag");
                ft.commit();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();                 
            }
        }
        else{
            calendarContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            calendarContainer = null;
        }
    }
```

XML-file:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/games_calendar_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stagelayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="95" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/games_calendar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@color/dark_gray" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

So, what the problem may be? Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` That line isn't needed for one.

Comment: Thanks, @DeeV. But it doesn't help, the perfomance is still very bad.

Comment: I am having a similar problem and would also like to know if anyone has figured it out

Comment: @jkau, no, it hasn't. I decided to do this in a popup-window, which works perfectly.